# Textview hides long text and view as well

Tags: android, xml, textview

- I created layout for action bar in which i used Linear Layout with weight 1 in which contain Textview for title and Imageview for icon.
- But when there is long text set in title it hides text and partial icon as well.
- You Can see in image.
- I need icon just Right to text there for i do not use weight=1 in textview.

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/actionbar_color"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgActionLeftIcon"
        android:layout_width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/action_btn_margine"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_logo" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtActionTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Medium Text ghjhjgjkghdfggh"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/action_btn_height_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgActionRightIcon"
        android:layout_width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/action_btn_margine"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_logo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue. See my code (added attribute `layout_weight`):

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtActionTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Medium Text ghjhjgjkghdfggh"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i also define above that i already used android:layout_weight="1" it works but issue is that if textview text is small then icon also put at last as looking margin between title and icon. That's why i didn't use android:layout_weight="1".

Comment: @Sam. Could you post a picture of what you need to achieve?